# Copiable mocks in Google Test Framework

Tags: c++, mocking, copy-constructor, googletest, copy-assignment

Is it possible to make a mock class copiable in **Google Test Framework**?
I've seen that the default **copy constructor** and **copy assignment operator** are deleted once that the `MOCK_METHOD` macros are used.
Is there a way to workaround that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot imagine any use case for copying mock objects. When you want to mimic real object with mock object - you shall have access to the very same object from code under test and from your test case code - so why copying needed?

Anyway - I see one method to make copying of mock object:
You have to define wrapper on mock object - which shall be kept by `std::shared_ptr`.

An example:

```
class XxxMock : public XxxInterface
{
public:
   MOCK_METHOD0(foo, void());
};

#include <memory>
class XxxSharedMock : public XxxInteface
{
public:
   XxxSharedMock(std::shared_ptr<XxxMock> xxxMock = std::make_shared<XxxMock>())
      : xxxMock(xxxMock) 
   {}
   void foo() override
   {
       xxxMock->foo();
   }
   // having: XxxSharedMock xxxMock; 
   // do:     EXPECT_CALL(xxxMock.mock(), foo());
   XxxMock& mock() { return *xxxMock; }
   XxxMock const& mock() const { return *xxxMock; }

privated:
   std::shared_ptr<XxxMock> xxxMock;
};
```